# How to get Current Shift?

Tags: sql-server

### Question

How can I retrieve the current shift record based on `getdate()` and which lies between the existing `ShiftStartTime` and `ShiftEndTime` as per the defined table and data?

It is possible get shift if the time reaches 12.00 AM?

### Table

```
create table ShiftMaster 
(
ShiftID char(4), 
ShiftName char(7), 
ShiftDescripiton varchar(20), 
ShiftStartTime time, 
ShiftEndTime time 
)
```

### Data

```
insert into ShiftMaster 
values 
('SHF1', 'Shift A', 'First Shift', '07:15:01', '15:45:00'), 
('SHF2', 'Shift B', 'Second Shift', '15:45:01', '00:15:00'),
('SHF3', 'Shift C', 'Third Shift', '00:15:01', '07:15:00')
```

#### Original Data (Screenshot)

[image]

### What I Have Tried

```
 SELECT * FROM VHASM2.ShiftMaster 
 WHERE FORMAT(getdate(),'HH:mm:ss') between ShiftStartTime and ShiftEndTime;
```

### dbfiddle and Alternate Statement

```
select * 
from ShiftMaster
where 
'' + cast(datepart(hh, getdate()) as char(2)) + ':' + cast(datepart(n, getdate()) as char(2)) + ':' + cast(datepart(ss, getdate()) as char(2)) + '' >= ShiftStartTime 
and 
'' + cast(datepart(hh, getdate()) as char(2)) + ':' + cast(datepart(n, getdate()) as char(2)) + ':' + cast(datepart(ss, getdate()) as char(2)) + '' <= ShiftEndTime
```

The [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9f62c1af8a73eab2b3c7a8bff28ebcb4) so far.

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql).

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. I have formatted your question somewhat and added some additonal help and a dbfiddle to give you a sense of how good questions are asked. I hope I got your data and DDL right? Please feel free to comment and update your question if need be by [editing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/228475/edit) it.

Comment: Thank you, not able to get 2nd shift from your Alternate Statement

Comment: Please tag your SQL Server version

Comment: Yes, I realise that. My edit and addition of an alternate solution in dbfiddle was to give you an idea of how you can present your question. It wasn't intended as a solution. I was working on it, but it seems @ypercubeᵀᴹ was faster. Please don't forget to accept the solution that works for you.

Answer (score 7):

You can separate the logic into 3 parts:

- first, for "normal" shifts, that don't include midnight
- and second and third for shifts that have midnight.

The query:

```
-- time now
declare @tn as time = getdate() ;

select *
from ShiftMaster
where ShiftStartTime <= @tn and @tn < ShiftEndTime
   or ShiftEndTime < ShiftStartTime and @tn < ShiftEndTime 
   or ShiftEndTime < ShiftStartTime and ShiftStartTime <= @tn 
  ;
```

Test in **[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fceac41f5cb92095f70d9b114239d14c)**.

---

Please also note that I used **closed-open intervals** and comparisons (**avoiding the evil `BETWEEN`<sup>*</sup>)**, so the shift `('00:15:00', '07:15:00')` stands for any time just of after `00:15` and before `07:15` (but not exactly 07:15). So every point in time should be in one and only one shift, assuming that you define the shifts correctly.

```
insert into ShiftMaster 
values 
('SHF1', 'Shift A', 'First Shift',
             '07:15:00', '15:45:00'),   -- notice the starts
('SHF2', 'Shift B', 'Second Shift',
             '15:45:00', '00:15:00'),   -- and the ends
('SHF3', 'Shift C', 'Third Shift',
             '00:15:00', '07:15:00') ;
```

With your method, there would be gaps of 1 second between shifts.

**<sup>*</sup>**: More info and detailed explanation about why to avoid `BETWEEN` with datetime types on the excellent blog post by Aaron Bertrand: [What do `BETWEEN` and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

Comment: thank you very much it solve my issue.I have one question, better i can use <= >= instead of between.

Comment: No, as I say in the second part, I strongly suggest to avoid BETWEEN (and `<=` `>=`) but use closed - open intervals (and `<=`, `<`). Also read the linked article (about BETWEEN and the devil).

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are seeing is because of the `00:15:00` value. My current time, `21:43:26` is bigger than `00:15:00` and thus, the `BETWEEN` check fails. Because SQL Server cannot know that it is referring to the next day, at 15 past midnight.

**A non-elegant, non-reusable work around**

```
 IF NOT EXISTS
 (
 SELECT * FROM dbo.ShiftMaster 
 WHERE cast(convert(varchar, getdate(), 108)as time) 
 BETWEEN ShiftStartTime and  ShiftEndTime) 
 BEGIN
 SELECT * from ShiftMaster where ShiftID = 'SHF2';
 END
 ELSE 
  SELECT * FROM dbo.ShiftMaster 
 WHERE cast(convert(varchar, getdate(), 108)as time) BETWEEN ShiftStartTime and  ShiftEndTime;
```

**Result**

> ```
> ShiftID   ShiftName   ShiftDescripiton    ShiftStartTime      ShiftEndTime
> SHF2      Shift B     Second Shift        15:45:01.0000000    00:15:00.0000000
> ```

I would wait / look into a more elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

If shifts don't change often you can use a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetShift(@Date DATETIME)
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Time time = CAST(@Date AS TIME);

    RETURN
    CASE WHEN @Time >= '07:15:01' AND @Time < '15:45:00' THEN 'SHIFT1'
         WHEN @Time >= '00:15:01' AND @Time < '07:15:00' THEN 'SHIFT3'
         ELSE 'SHIFT2' END;
END

SELECT dbo.GetShift(GETDATE());
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b5e18aa705b495bb9879e80407a67d44)*

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simple enter 2 records for Second shift? It will solve your problem.

```
insert into #ShiftMaster 
values 
('SHF1', 'Shift A', 'First Shift', '07:15:01', '15:45:00'), 
('SHF2', 'Shift B', 'Second Shift', '00:00:00', '00:15:00'),
('SHF2', 'Shift B', 'Second Shift', '15:45:01', '23:59:59'),
('SHF3', 'Shift C', 'Third Shift', '00:15:01', '07:15:00')

SELECT x.PunchTime, ShiftID, ShiftName
FROM ( VALUES (CONVERT(CHAR(8),GetDate(),108))
    , ('00:00:01'), ('00:00:00'), ('23:17:00')
    , ('01:25:00'), ('08:49:00'), ('13:00:00')
    , ('16:27:00')) x(PunchTime)
INNER JOIN #ShiftMaster as s 
    ON x.PunchTime BETWEEN ShiftStartTime and ShiftEndTime
```

Answer (score 0):

in my `ShiftMaster` table , I have added one column `Shifthr char(5)` which will contain hour value in format like `"09:00"'

Suppose Shift hour is common for all shift then this column is not require,storing the value in variable will do.

So,in my script I am not using `ShiftEnd` column.

I have assume that you will pass parameter in format `'02:15:00'` or `'00:00:00'`

So in my sample Ignore ShiftEnd column value,

```
create table #ShiftMaster(shiftID char(4),ShiftName varchar(20),descriptions varchar(50)
,shiftStart time,shiftEnd time,Shifthr char(5))
insert into #ShiftMaster 
values 
('SHF1', 'Shift A', 'First Shift', '07:15:01', '16:15:01','09:00'), 
('SHF2', 'Break', 'n Shift', '23:30:59', '08:30:59','09:00'),
('SHF2', 'Shift B', 'Second Shift', '15:45:01', '00:45:01','09:00'),
 ('SHF3', 'Shift C', 'Third Shift', '00:15:01', '09:15:01','09:00')
```

First Manipulate input,

```
declare @input time='00:00:00' -- pass paramteter

declare @DateTimeinput datetime -- Local paramter to add date in input

declare @CurDate Datetime=cast(getdate() as date)

if( datepart(hour,@input)=0)
    set @DateTimeinput=dateadd(day,1,@CurDate)+cast(@input as DATETIME)
ELSE
    set @DateTimeinput=@CurDate+cast(@input as DATETIME)


select * from #ShiftMaster
where @DateTimeinput
BETWEEN (@CurDate+ cast(shiftStart as DATETIME)) 
and (@CurDate+ cast(shiftStart as DATETIME)+cast(Shifthr as DATETIME))

drop table #ShiftMaster
```

PLEASE ignore `ShiftEnd` column or put valid data.